# FlexSlider caption ipad issue

Tags: ipad, anchor, caption, flexslider

Ok this one has me stumped. I have an implementation of FlexSlider on this [site](http://fabricomagazine.com)

Everything seems to work fine in every browser on my desktop, even safari.

The problems I am having appear to be iPad specific.

For some reason, no matter how many slides I add, on the iPad the caption anchor always links to the same post (the first slide/caption that was added). The text changes when you move slides, but the anchor link stays the same.
I have tried disabling my stylings thinking it may be some dodgy CSS but nope, same issue still.

The issue is only apparent on the iPad (maybe the iPhone too?) but ive got no idea how to fix this.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where on mobile (iPhone/iPad) the link of the last slide became the link for all slides.

I didn't find a solution but setting the "animation" property to "slide" instead of "fade" has worked for me until there is a better fix.